# Qt 4.7 Unicode conversion of string

Tags: qt, unicode, utf-8

We have inherited some legacy code written in QT 4.7.4 and this cannot be changed as there are too many dependencies.

The code uses an OGR library to read a char string from Postgres which is then rendered to a canvas in Qt using a Painter object.

```
The name La Rosière is read in as follows:-

CHAR   0 'L'  :  76 
CHAR   1 'a'  :  97
CHAR   2 ' '  :  32 
CHAR   3 'R'  :  82 
CHAR   4 'o'  :  111 
CHAR   5 's'  :  115 
CHAR   6 'i'  :  105 
CHAR   7 ''  :  195
CHAR   8 ''  :  168 
CHAR   9 'r'  :  114 
CHAR   10 'e'  :  101
```

As you can see chars 7 and 8 are c3 a8 in hex which is the correctly accented è

In Qt 4.7.4 how can I convert this to a UTF-8 QString that will be properly rendered? I have tried the following but they all dump La Rosire to qDebug()

```
QString::fromLatin1();
QString::fromStdString();
QString::fromUtf8();
QObject::tr();

QPainter is printing characters 7 and 8 separately Like "La RosiA^re"
```

Comment: That is UTF-8, so the correct method for constructing a QString fron that char array is `QString::fromUtf8()`. How is it been printed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is to differentiate between characters that are encoded with a single byte and those that require two (or more) bytes to encode.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

*"One-byte codes are used only for the ASCII values 0 through 127"*

*"Code points larger than 127 are represented by multi-byte sequences, composed of a leading byte and one or more continuation bytes"*

```
┌────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│Bits of │First   │Last     │Bytes in │Byte 1   │Byte 2   │Byte 3   │Byte 4  │
│code    │code    │code     │sequence │         │         │         │        │
│point   │point   │point    │         │         │         │         │        │
├────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┤
│7       │U+0000  │U+007F   │1        │0xxxxxxx │         │         │        │
├────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┤
│11      │U+0080  │U+07FF   │2        │110xxxxx │10xxxxxx │         │        │
├────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┤
│16      │U+0800  │U+FFFF   │3        │1110xxxx │10xxxxxx │10xxxxxx │        │
├────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┤
│21      │U+10000 │U+1FFFFF │4        │11110xxx │10xxxxxx │10xxxxxx │10xxxxxx│
└────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

So you need to figure out if the current character is the start of a multi-byte Unicode character

**Quick And Dirty Pseudo Code**

`if (CharToInt > 127) 
    Use this and the next char as a two byte Unicode Character
else
    Use just this character`

**Doing It Properly Pseudo Code**

`if (first bit of char is zero)
    Use just this character
else if (first two bits are one)
    Use this and the next char as a two byte Unicode Character
else if (first three bits are one)
    Use this and the next two chars as a three byte Unicode Character
else if (first three bits are one)
    Use this and the next three chars as a four byte Unicode Character`

Comment: Thanks I get the pseudo code but how do I actually build up a UTF-8 QString object in  QT? I get the theory, now need help with the practical  ;-)

Comment: Don't have access to Qt-creator at the moment, but you probably want QString::QString(const QChar * unicode, int size = -1) or QString::QString(const QByteArray & ba) from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Answer (score 0):

OK I have solved this and am embarrassed as I should have read further back into the code.

The programmer had initialised the string as follows:-

```
= QString::fromStdString(...)
```

I replaced fromstdString with fromUtf8 and all is good.